# If I FaceTime from iPhone can someone watch/listen to it in real time on the iPad that has same Apple ID?

Tags: facetime

If I make a FaceTime call on my iPhone, can anyone watch/listen to it on the iPad if the iPad has the same Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

Not using the ordinary FaceTime software, no.

If you actually call the iPad and/or add it to the call, they can ofcourse listen as they are part of the call and listed as such.